# Devise looses i18n.locale when authenticate_user! kicks in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oauth, devise

I have a multilangual Rails 4.0.2 / Ruby 2.1.0 application.
Devise is used to enable email / password + Facebook oAuth.
The translations on my pages are all working fine;
this is more about the routing.

Flow of the feature I'm having problems with:

- visitor decides to vote on an item ( using ':locale/products/:uuid/vote' path )
- visitor has to be authenticated ( email / pwd or facebook oauth )
- `before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :vote`
- authentication kicks in and
- authenticated visitor ( = user ) is redirected to vote url

The biggest issue right now is Devise loses the current I18n.locale setting. 
So in stead of going to :locale/account/welcome I get redirected to account/welcome.
I've tried to replicate the behaviour with a new app and sure enough,
my problem popped back up.

How can I keep my application flow in the I18n.locale context using Devise 
and it's default flow of auth / registration / redirects?

```
class GalleryController < ApplicationController
    include ApplicationHelper
    skip_before_action :set_locale, only: :vote
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :vote

    def vote
        …
    end
end
```

The before_action from `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def set_locale
        # trying to set language with params[:locale]
        if MyApp.valid_locale?(params[:locale])
          I18n.locale = cookies.permanent[:locale] = params[:locale]
        else
          store_location
          redirect_to root_url unless :devise_controller?
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: did you find a solution ? I got the same issue...  and the default_url options does not solved it as I18n.locale is reset to default upon FB callback

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this method to `ApplicationController`

```
def self.default_url_options
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It works for me. However, in [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:--Redirect-with-locale-after-authentication-failure), they suggest `options.merge({ :locale => I18n.locale })`. Could you please tell me the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the current locale in session

```
# ApplicationController

before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  session[:locale] = I18n.locale
end

def default_url_options(options = {})
  { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
end
```

Comment: This seems to work for me. On initial tests anyway. How likely is it that the session would be lost in the space of the user logging in?

Comment: The Rails Guide advises *against* storing the locale in the session: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/i18n.html#storing-the-locale-from-the-session-or-cookies